# Rails - converting text to unordered list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, list

Is there anyway to convert text from a record to unordered list shown on one of the pages with Ruby on Rails?
I was looking through Google but couldn't find anything fitting.

Let's say:

Thing 1; Thing 2; Thing 3; Thing 4; Thing 5

To:

```
Thing 1
Thing 2
Thing 3
Thing 4
Thing 5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
"Thing 1; Thing 2; Thing 3; Thing 4; Thing 5".split(";").each do |thing|
  puts thing
end
```

[`split`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/String.html#method-i-split) converts the string into an array, with each element being delimited by `;`. Then we iterate through the array using `each` and output the element.

If you want an html list, you can do this, say, if you working with slim templates, or haml, or erb.

```
- things = "Thing 1; Thing 2; Thing 3; Thing 4; Thing 5".split(";")
<ul>
  things.each { |thing| "<li>#{thing}</li>" }
</ul>
```

Of course, ideally you would not have the logic in the view template, but you get the point.

This solution assumes your items are delimited by a semi-colon character.

Comment: Thanks for fast response, looks like this is what I was looking for